# Google Music app update in UK

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-music

I am UK based and have a Nexus 1 and Nexus S both running stock Android 2.3.4.

On both devices, I have a manual update pending for the Music app from Google Inc., but when I go in to the Market to view this app, I get an AlertDialog telling me that "The requested item could not be found."

I understand that Google Music is only available in the US, but why is the Market telling me that I need to update the app, only to tell me that it is not available when I try to?

Comment: Interesting. I'm getting the same problem, but I assumed it was because I'd side loaded the update when it became available and the Marketplace doesn't know where the apk is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an updated version of the Music App (new, fancy UI), supposedly ready for full Google Music Cloud, for when it comes to the UK.

I was unable to view the details in the market like yourself, but I could actually do the update. Nexus S on 2.3.4 too.

Did you by any chance get an update notification for Google Books too?

Comment: I never actually tried long clicking on it and selecting "Update". Doing that installs it.